# Change time variable in netCDF to datetime with pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netCDF file where the time is in days since, I guess, 1 Jan 0000. But, they are in integers, see below, and once loaded xarray cannot decode the time units.

```
<xarray.DataArray 'days' (time: 87600)>
array([679352., 679353., 679354., ..., 766949., 766950., 766951.])
Dimensions without coordinates: time
Attributes:
    units:      days_since_Jan11900
    long_name:  calendar_days
```

I want to turn them into datetime with pandas. I have done this so far

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset(path + '09_future_predictions/Fire weather/temp/tmax_HadGEM2-CC.nc', decode_times = False)

tmax = ds.tmax.data
time = ds.days
time = pd.to_datetime(time.data)
```

But, I end up with pandas reading the integers as milliseconds, see below:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-01 00:00:00.000679352',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000679353',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000679354',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000679360',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000679361',
               ...
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000766942',
        
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=87600, freq=None)
```

What can I do to change it so the first variable is `1860-01-01`?

Comment: Why can't you read it as a normal float/int to pandas and then use apply functions like netcdf.num2date/matplotlib.date.num2date ?

Comment: How? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself by doing this. Note I am working with 365-day-a-year calendar, and I changed 01 Jan 0000 to 01 Jan 1860 in the second line of coding.

```
ds = xr.open_dataset(path + 'temp/tmax_HadGEM2-CC.nc', decode_times = False)
ds['days'] = ds.days - 679352
ds.days.attrs['units'] = 'days since 1860-01-01'
ds['days'].attrs['calendar'] = 'noleap'
ds = xr.decode_cf(ds)
ds = ds.loc[dict(time = slice(66430,73000))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly with netCDF, but if it can help.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as md

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [679352., 679353., 679354., 766949., 766950., 766951.]})

df_1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   c1      6 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 176.0 bytes

df_1.c1.apply(md.num2date)
0   1861-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
1   1861-01-02 00:00:00+00:00
2   1861-01-03 00:00:00+00:00
3   2100-11-01 00:00:00+00:00
4   2100-11-02 00:00:00+00:00
5   2100-11-03 00:00:00+00:00
Name: c1, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```